# TextView setText() does not work

Tags: java, android

I have the following problem in my Android app:

setText does not changes text of textviews

Some strings and doubles must be sent via intent and must be displayed in textviews

code part where i send extra messages:

```
private void showInfo(PointOfInterest poi){
        Intent intent  = new Intent(this, ShowInfo.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", poi.getName().toString());
        intent.putExtra("city", poi.getCity().toString());
        intent.putExtra("country", poi.getCountry().toString());
        intent.putExtra("date", poi.getDate().toString());
        intent.putExtra("comment", poi.getComment().toString());
        intent.putExtra("cat", poi.getCategorie().toString());
        intent.putExtra("lng", poi.getLng());
        intent.putExtra("lat", poi.getLat());

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

i try to display them:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_show_info); 
    namePoi = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showNameInfo);
    TextView city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showCityInfo);
    TextView country = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showCountryInfo);
    TextView date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showDateInfo);
    TextView comment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showCommentInfo);
    TextView cat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showCatInfo);

    lat = intent.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0);
    lng = intent.getDoubleExtra("lng", 0);
    TextView latView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showLatInfo);
    TextView lngView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showLngInfo);
    Log.d("debug", intent.getStringExtra("cat"));
    CharSequence tmp = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    name.setText(tmp);
    city.setText(intent.getStringExtra("city"));
    country.setText(intent.getStringExtra("country"));
    date.setText(intent.getStringExtra("date"));
    comment.setText(intent.getStringExtra("comment"));
    name.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name"));
    cat.setText(intent.getStringExtra("cat"));
    lngView.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    latView.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_info); 
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

xml fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.pointsofinterest.ShowInfo$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showNameInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" " />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showDateInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" " />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Country:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showCountryInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" " />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showCityInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" " />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Latitude:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showLatInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" " />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Longitude:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showLngInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" " />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Categorie:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showCatInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" " />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Comment:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showCommentInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" " />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
            android:text="Show on Map" 
            android:onClick="showOnMap"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

there are no errors in logcat, i just see my activity with empty textviews

Comment: What is in PlaceholderFragment? If you are using Fragments, you should be creating the view in the Fragment's onCreateView() method. And of course, provide the intent's data to the fragment as placeholderFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

And you need to say more about the error than just "doesn't work". What is the error? What is the logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onCreate() function is wrong.

```
....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_info); 
    PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(intent.getExtras());
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

PlaceHolderFragment:

```
...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_info, container, false);
    namePoi = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showNameInfo);
    city = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showCityInfo);
    country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showCountryInfo);
    date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showDateInfo);
    comment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showCommentInfo);
    cat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showCatInfo);

    lat = getArguments().getDouble("lat", 0);
    lng = getArguments().getDouble("lng", 0);
    latView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showLatInfo);
    lngView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showLngInfo);
    Log.d("debug", getArguments().getString("cat"));
    CharSequence tmp = getArguments().getString("name");
    name.setText(tmp);
    city.setText(getArguments().getString("city"));
    country.setText(getArguments().getString("country"));
    date.setText(getArguments().getString("date"));
    comment.setText(getArguments().getString("comment"));
    name.setText(getArguments().getString("name"));
    cat.setText(getArguments().getString("cat"));
    lngView.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    latView.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    return view;
}
```